# How to get a div to indicate, that another div is being toggled(displayed in slideshow)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am looking for a way to show that a div is being toggled, with a separate div indicator ".bars"

I have tried if statements and added classes to the indicator ".bars" to change its properties...

The indicator ".bars" has three children divs each representing a toggled div in 
a slideshow...

```
if($(".one")).show(){
$(".bars div").css(change it here);
}
//what I am confused about is that I can change other html elements this way 
like the parent div which is indicator ".bar" but I cant seem to change its children...
<div class="bars">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Here is my codepen link to show where I am having difficulty
http://codepen.io/gebrutommy/pen/ZpGZRv?editors=0010

Comment: Can you provide the rest of your markup and, better still, an image of what you're trying to accomplish?  I don't see an element with ".one" or ".indicator". Also, what are you trying to test in that if statement?

Comment: yeah of course, this is my codepen...
http://codepen.io/gebrutommy/pen/ZpGZRv?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly... I added a bit of code to you `focusNextDiv` function to add a class for highlighting:

JS:

```
function focusNextDiv() {
  $(".gallery").hide();
  divs[index].toggle();

  // Added JS
  var bars = $('.bars div').removeClass('current');
  $(bars.get(index)).addClass('current');
  // End of Added JS

  index++; 
  if (index === divs.length) {
    index = 0;
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.bars div.current {
  background-color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="bars flex row">
    <div class="current"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
```

This can be cleaned up, but I just wanted to make sure I understood the problem correctly. Is this closer to what you're looking for?

This code uses your `index` variable and looks in the `.bars` div for a child with the same index, then just adds a `.current` class to it.  I manually added the same `.current` class to your markup so on page load, the first `.bar` div is shown as selected.

[Working Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrOLWg)

Comment: BTW: Initializing your index variable at 0 will make the first div appear to display for 10 seconds when the page first loads, then 5 seconds between each display after that.  (If that's not intended, initial your index variable at 1.

Comment: Do I have to answer questions on SO to get my votes to count??
Also I just saw the Working Codepen link that was truly helpful, thanks so much!

Comment: @user3657227 You're welcome and yes you do need reputation points to vote. You CAN, however, click the grey check mark icon next to the correct answer to "accept it" and it will give you some reputation points.  Ask and "accept" questions and you will quickly earn enough reputation points to vote and gain other site privileges (like removing site ads, etc.).